# Cut off start and end of mp3 file with ffmpeg - without having to specify file duration? Windows batch

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, trim

I have hundreds of mp3 files, all random lengths.

I want to cut 10 seconds off the beginning and 10 seconds off the end of each file - without having to tell ffmpeg the duration of each file.

Here's an example where you already know the file is 1 minute long. It removes from 50 seconds onwards and removes the first 10 seconds, but this is no use on hundreds of random length mp3 files, because it requires you to know the file is 1 minute long...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:50 -c copy output.mp3
```

I have looked for hours and not found a solution.

I honestly think this is impossible but I'm asking here just in case :)

Comment: One possible way would be to use ffmpeg (or ffprobe) to get the length of the mp3 and then calculate the `-t` value from that. It requires a bit of coding though.

Comment: One way that looked like it might work was using `-sseof` but I couldn't get it working. The ffmpeg documentation says "negative values are earlier in the file" so I tested trying to cut 10 seconds by doing `-00:-00:-10` but nothing was output. I'm not sure if I used `-t` with it though. There's this top answer from Gyan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515420/cut-video-with-ffmpeg but that first command didn't work (maybe because of the 2017 bug). `ffmpeg -ss 10 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[b][0]overlay=shortest=1" -shortest -c:a copy out.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it. I've only added mp3 and mp4 files at the moment but the concept of it is there and it's been tested and works. Although the below does work, it can be improved and I'll edit the revised version into this post once I have it all worked out.

**Trim Start and End.bat**

```
rem    Make this command window miminize itself...
:: if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit

cd /d %~dp0
cls
@echo off
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem
rem    Trim X seconds from start and/or end of media file.
rem
rem    Supported file types:
rem    - 3gp, asf, avi, flv, gif, m4v, mkv, mov, mp4, mpeg, mpg, rm, rmvb, swf, vob, webm, wmv.
rem    
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
title Trim Start and End of Media Files
color 0f

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cls
if not exist ..\*.3gp if not exist ..\*.aac if not exist ..\*.aiff if not exist ..\*.asf ^
if not exist ..\*.avi if not exist ..\*.flac if not exist ..\*.flv if not exist ..\*.m4a ^
if not exist ..\*.m4v if not exist ..\*.mkv if not exist ..\*.mov if not exist ..\*.mp3 ^
if not exist ..\*.mp4 if not exist ..\*.mpeg if not exist ..\*.mpg if not exist ..\*.ogg ^
if not exist ..\*.opus if not exist ..\*.ra if not exist ..\*.rm if not exist ..\*.rmvb ^
if not exist ..\*.swf if not exist ..\*.vob if not exist ..\*.wav if not exist ..\*.webm ^
if not exist ..\*.wma if not exist ..\*.wmv ^
goto no_audio_or_video

if exist ..\*.3gp if exist ..\*.aac if exist ..\*.aiff if exist ..\*.asf ^
if exist ..\*.avi if exist ..\*.flac if exist ..\*.flv if exist ..\*.m4a ^
if exist ..\*.m4v if exist ..\*.mkv if exist ..\*.mov if exist ..\*.mp3 ^
if exist ..\*.mp4 if exist ..\*.mpeg if exist ..\*.mpg if exist ..\*.ogg ^
if exist ..\*.opus if exist ..\*.ra if exist ..\*.rm if exist ..\*.rmvb ^
if exist ..\*.swf if exist ..\*.vob if exist ..\*.wav if exist ..\*.webm ^
if exist ..\*.wma if exist ..\*.wmv ^
goto continue

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:continue
rem    Set the amount of seconds to trim from the start and end of media file...
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set GAP=%%A
cls
echo.
echo    ------------------------------------------------------------
echo                 Trim Start and End of Media File(s)
echo    ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo        The start and end figures must be typed in seconds.
echo.
echo          Here are some examples of minutes, in seconds...
echo.
echo       [2 Minutes = 120 Seconds]    [3 Minutes = 180 Seconds]
echo       [5 Minutes = 300 Seconds]    [10 Minutes = 600 Seconds]
echo      [30 Minutes = 1800 Seconds]  [60 Minutes = 3600 Seconds]
echo.
echo    ------------------------------------------------------------
echo    If you are only trimming the end, put 0 as the start figure.
echo    If you are only trimming the start, put 0 as the end figure.
echo    ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
set /p start_trim="%GAP%   Please type how many seconds to cut off the START: "
echo.
set /p end_trim="%GAP%   Please type how many seconds to cut off the END: "
echo.
echo    Please wait...

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Set a randomly named folder to allow multiple batch files to run without mixing up files...
set rnd_temp=%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%
md %rnd_temp%

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Move video/audio file from one folder up, to current folder...
if exist "..\*.3gp" move /y "..\*.3gp" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.aac" move /y "..\*.aac" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.aiff" move /y "..\*.aiff" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.asf" move /y "..\*.asf" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.avi" move /y "..\*.avi" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.flac" move /y "..\*.flac" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.flv" move /y "..\*.flv" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.m4a" move /y "..\*.m4a" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.m4v" move /y "..\*.m4v" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.mkv" move /y "..\*.mkv" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.mov" move /y "..\*.mov" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.mp3" move /y "..\*.mp3" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.mp4" move /y "..\*.mp4" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.mpeg" move /y "..\*.mpeg" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.mpg" move /y "..\*.mpg" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.ogg" move /y "..\*.ogg" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.opus" move /y "..\*.opus" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.ra" move /y "..\*.ra" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.rm" move /y "..\*.rm" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.rmvb" move /y "..\*.rmvb" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.swf" move /y "..\*.swf" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.vob" move /y "..\*.vob" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.wav" move /y "..\*.wav" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.webm" move /y "..\*.webm" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.wma" move /y "..\*.wma" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1
if exist "..\*.wmv" move /y "..\*.wmv" "%rnd_temp%" >nul 2>&1

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Remove non-standard characters from file names in the "%rnd_temp%"
rem    folder, because ffmpeg cannot handle those characters...
xcopy "SpecialChar\*.bat" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
cd /d %rnd_temp%
call rename.bat >nul 2>&1
cd /d ..
del "%rnd_temp%\*.bat"
 
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Create OLD and NEW folders for files to be moved to...
if not exist "..\OLD" md "..\OLD"
if not exist "..\NEW" md "..\NEW"


rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    FILE PROCESSING STARTS HERE:
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cls
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    --------------- mp4 files --------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    Trim the start of mp4 files (one at a time) using seconds specified in %start_trim% and move old files to the OLD folder...
md "%rnd_temp%\new_mp4"
if exist %rnd_temp%\*.mp4 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b %rnd_temp%\*.mp4') DO start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%rnd_temp%\%%G" -ss %start_trim% -c copy "%rnd_temp%\new_mp4\%%~nG.mp4" -hide_banner & move /y "%rnd_temp%\%%G" "..\OLD" >nul 2>&1

rem    Move the new files out of new_mp4, to the root of %rnd_temp% (old files were already moved to the OLD folder)...
move /y "%rnd_temp%\new_mp4\*.mp4" "%rnd_temp%"

rem    Remove the now empty "%rnd_temp%\new_mp4" folder...
rd "%rnd_temp%\new_mp4"

rem    Start the process to trim the end of mp4 files...
goto trim_end_mp4

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Trim the end of mp4 files (one at a time) using seconds specified in %end_trim% and move old files to the OLD folder...
:trim_end_mp4
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\Trim_mp4.bat" xcopy "TrimStartEnd\Trim_mp4.bat" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\ffmpeg.exe" xcopy "ffmpeg.exe" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\ffprobe.exe" xcopy "ffprobe.exe" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1

for %%i in (%rnd_temp%\*.mp4) do (
call "%rnd_temp%\Trim_mp4.bat" "%%i"
)



cls
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    --------------- mp3 files --------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    ----------------------------------------
rem    Trim the start of mp3 files (one at a time) using seconds specified in %start_trim% and move old files to the OLD folder...
md "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3"
if exist %rnd_temp%\*.mp3 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b %rnd_temp%\*.mp3') DO start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%rnd_temp%\%%G" -ss %start_trim% -c copy "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3\%%~nG.mp3" -hide_banner & move /y "%rnd_temp%\%%G" "..\OLD" >nul 2>&1

rem    Move the new files out of new_mp3, to the root of %rnd_temp% (old files were already moved to the OLD folder)...
move /y "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3\*.mp3" "%rnd_temp%"

rem    Remove the now empty "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3" folder...
rd "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3"

rem    Start the process to trim the end of mp3 files...
goto trim_end_mp3

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Trim the end of mp3 files (one at a time) using seconds specified in %end_trim% and move old files to the OLD folder...
:trim_end_mp3
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\Trim_mp3.bat" xcopy "TrimStartEnd\Trim_mp3.bat" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\ffmpeg.exe" xcopy "ffmpeg.exe" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\ffprobe.exe" xcopy "ffprobe.exe" "%rnd_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1

for %%i in (%rnd_temp%\*.mp3) do (
call "%rnd_temp%\Trim_mp3.bat" "%%i"
)

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    


rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Delete ffmpeg.exe, ffprobe.exe and trim bat files from "%rnd_temp%"
if exist "%rnd_temp%\ffmpeg.exe" del "%rnd_temp%\ffmpeg.exe"
if exist "%rnd_temp%\ffprobe.exe" del "%rnd_temp%\ffprobe.exe"
if exist "%rnd_temp%\Trim_*.bat" del "%rnd_temp%\Trim_*.bat"

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Remove the random folder...
rd "%rnd_temp%\" >nul 2>&1
goto trim_complete

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:trim_complete
cls
echo.
echo    Process is complete.
echo.
echo    %start_trim% seconds were cut off the start.
echo    %end_trim% seconds were cut off the end.
echo.
echo    Exiting...
timeout 15 >nul
goto finished

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:no_audio_or_video
cls
echo.
echo.
echo    There are no audio or video files to trim.
echo.
echo    Exiting...
timeout 8 >nul
goto finished

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:finished
exit
```

The **TrimStartEnd** folder contains **Trim_mp3.bat**, **Trim_mp4.bat** etc but I'll just post the commands for Trim_mp3.bat here:

**TrimStartEnd\Trim_mp3.bat**

```
@echo off

cls
rem    Use ffprobe to get the duration...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('ffprobe -show_format -i %1 ^| find "duration"') do set _duration=%%a
set _duration=%_duration:~9%
for /f "delims=. tokens=1*" %%b in ('echo %_duration%') do set /a "_durS=%%b"
for /f "delims=. tokens=2*" %%c in ('echo %_duration%') do set "_durMS=%%c"

cls
rem     Trim the end by the amount specified in %end_trim% (specified in parent batch file)
set /a "_durS-=%end_trim%"
set "_newduration=%_durS%.%_durMS%"
set "_output=%~n1"
if not exist "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3" md "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3"
start /wait /min ffmpeg.exe -y -ss 0 -i %1 -t %_newduration% -c copy "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3\%_output%.mp3"

rem    Move the new file "%_output%.mp3" (that now has start and end trimmed) from "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3" to the NEW folder...
move /y "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3\%_output%.mp3" "..\NEW" >nul 2>&1

rem    Delete leftover mp3 file that only had the start trimmed...
if exist %1 del %1

rem    Delete the (now empty) "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3" folder...
if exist "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3" rd "%rnd_temp%\new_mp3"

rem    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Now this whole process will repeat until all mp3 files have been processed.
rem    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The file and folder structure is like this:

```
ROOT\ffmpeg.exe 
ROOT\ffprobe.exe
ROOT\Trim Start and End.bat <--- parent batch file
ROOT\TrimStartEnd\Trim_mp3.bat <--- called by parent batch file
```

Now where do your mp3/mp4 etc files go you might wonder - they go next to the ROOT folder.

The nice thing about this is, you can trim only the start, only the end, or both.

This isn't a clean solution because it copies ffmpeg and ffprobe to the working folder but I don't know a way around that. Maybe someone else does, hint hint.

Enjoy!